# hash join in spark scala on pair rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, rdd

I am trying to perform a partition+broadcast join in spark scala. I have a dictionary that I am broadcasting to all the nodes. The structure of the dictionary is as follows:

```
{ key: Option[List[Strings]] } // I created this dictionary using a groupByKey first and then called collectAsMap before broadcasting.
```

The above dictionary was created using the table whose structure is similar to the table mentioned below.

I have a table that is a pair RDD whose structure is as follows:
`Col A | Col B`

I am trying to perform a join as follows:

```
    val join_output = table.flatMap{
      case(key, value) => custom_dictionary.value.get(key).map(
        otherValue => otherValue.foreach((value, _))
      )
    }
```

My goal is to get a pair-RDD as an output whose contents are ( from table,  from list stored in the dictionary).

The code runs and compiles successfully but when I check the output, I only see this: "()" as the output being saved. Where am I going wrong?
I did have a look at some of the other posts that did reflect up to some extent on this matter, but none of the options worked. I request some guidance on this issue. Also, if there is a post that exactly points to this, please let me know.

Comment: foreach returns Unit

Comment: But if I use a for statement as ``` for (elem <- otherValue) {(value, elem)}```, then too I get the same output.

Comment: because a for loop is not an expression. It does not return any value

Comment: Can u show complete code pls?